# get substring until nth match regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the string:

```
"Hello world; some random text; foo; bla bla; "
```

what regular expresion could I use in order to get a substring until the second `;` .

In other words I will like to end up with the substring `"Hello world; some random text;"`

or maybe I want to get the substring until the 3th ; thus ending up with:

```
"Hello world; some random text; foo;"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one. Should work just fine.

```
/([\w\s]+?\;){2}/
```

Used as follows:

```
var str = "Hello world; some random text; foo; bla bla; ";
var match = str.match(/([^;]*;){2}/)[0];
alert(match); // Hello world; some random text;
```

Comment: Could probably even simplify that to `/([^;];){2}/`.

Comment: I don't know how to call it. Please post all the code required to use this Reg Exp.

Comment: `var str = "Hello world; some random text; foo; bla bla; ";`
`var match = str.match(/([\w\s]+?\;){2}/)[0];`

Comment: Details: The first regexp is now different from the one in the example. I suggest the one in the example, as it doesn't have an unnecessary limitation on which characters are allowed in the substrings.

Comment: Also, it would fail if there is an empty substring (`""`) between two semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to use Regex, you could use the Split() method with a semicolon separator:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a problem that is best solved with RegExps. Very easy to do it with straight JS. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/xvM53/1/

```
var str = "Hello world; some random text; foo; bla bla; ";
function getParts(str, delimiter, partCount) {
  return str.split(delimiter,partCount).join(";");
}
```

Credit where it's due: I shamelessly used diEcho's idea, I didn't remember you could pass a second parameter to split.

Comment: To be really picky, the final semicolon is still missing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

why regex??

do it in simple way

```
var str = "Hello world; some random text; foo; bla bla; "
alert(str.split(";",2).join(";"));
```

[`reference`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: That way, the semicolons would get lost, wouldn't they?

Comment: This still has the same bug as what I suggested (we had the same idea), it's missing the last semi-colon, but that's very easy to fix.

Comment: @diEcho Yes. The `join` fix solved part of it, but the last last semicolon is still missing. (As @Juan is saying.)